# How can I access the branches in my git repository via URLs?

Tags: git, branch

I've been planning on using GIT for version control. However, I have a prolly stupid question in my mind.

Say I have a server with PHP configured and I am using it to develop websites that I can access by servername/website. Once I initialize git in that directory, it automatically creates a master repository. What if I create a few branches say (Branch1, Branch2) etc.

Once I make changes to Branch1, Branch2 etc ... how can I view the changes via a URL?
When I go to sername/website, will it show me only the contents of what is present in the master branch?

Also if I remove a file by doing rm filename from one branch, I know it also deletes it from the server. However if I switch branches, I see that the file exists within that branch, but not on the server. That seems weird to me? How can I access a file that doesn't exist? (I am aware that git rm --cached, keeps the file on the server and only deletes it from the branch ... but I was curious, nonetheless ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once I make changes to Branch1,
>   Branch2 etc ... how can I view the
>   changes via a URL? When I go to
>   sername/website, will it show me only
>   the contents of what is present in the
>   master branch?

Yes, the server will show you the files that are checked out.

> Also if I remove a file by doing rm
>   filename from one branch, I know it
>   also deletes it from the server.

It does not delete the file from the server, only that commit in that branch (and most probably the commits following in the same branch) do not reference that file anymore in the tree.

> I am aware that git rm --cached, keeps
>   the file on the server and only
>   deletes it from the branch ... but I
>   was curious, nonetheless ..

Not really, that deletes the file from the staging area in your current git setup (on the machine you are working on).

To come back to your original problem, you can probably setup some CGI script that would checkout a different branch for your website, but still every user accessing the same website will all see the same thing.

If you want a web interface to look at the changes you are making, you should look into [git-php](http://code.google.com/p/git-php/) or something like that.

**EDIT** Since the answer to your comment is not short, I am adding here...

No ! Every branch is cloned and stored in the .git folder, you are checking out only one branch (or one commit) at a time. You "view" only one version of the code at a time, only everything in the repository is also stored on your computer in the .git folder.

One (easy way if you don't have too many branches) is to have as many clones as you have branches. Something like this :

```
www
|-- branch1
|   |-- .git
|   |   |-- config
|   |   `-- other-git-object
|   `-- index.html
|-- branch2
|   |-- .git
|   |   |-- config
|   |   `-- other-git-object
|   `-- index.html
`-- master
    |-- .git
    |   |-- config
    |   `-- other-git-object
    `-- index.html
```

Comment: "To come back to your original problem, you can probably setup some CGI script that would checkout a different branch for your website, but still every user accessing the same website will all see the same thing." ... Matt, can you elaborate on this. I am confused. So when you say the server will show me what files, I checkout. Which files are these? Every branch needs to be "checked out" right? Ideally, I'd want to be able to access every branch of the project via a URL if that is possible ...

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt for your effort. Sorry for the late reply! But this makes more sense now! Thanks again ...

Comment: There is something i am not sure to understand, if i checkout the Branche_1, so the URL of my website will show the code from the Branche_1 right ? But is there is something wrong, all my users are now using the Branch_1 code i am testing before merging...? How to avoid that ? Like testing a branche before merging with a specific URL

Comment: @Ludo, I am not sure I understand your problem... sounds like maybe this is more a problem with your users and your code than the setup with git and the webserver as the original question?

Comment: No. The problem is that if we use only one URL and checkout on different branchesin order to test them we are going to have serious issues if we have a traffic on the web app (if there is a bug on a branche we are testing).